# Concatenate multiple fields where some fields are empty

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table named tblFriends, see below:

[image]

I would like to concatenate the first row, but the number of columns fluctuates daily.

Lets say that the fields names are 1, 2, 3, 4...30 (where 30 is the max number of fields possible.)

How do I concatenate all the string text in these fields? Also, will it cause an error for empty fields? For example if, as the table shows, there are only 4 fields with records in them will it give me an error if I still try and concat all 30 fields?

This is the code I was planning on using but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Dim strSQLCat As String

strSQLCat = "UPDATE tblFriends SET 31 = CONCAT( 1 & ',' & 2 & ',' & 3 & '....' & 30) Where Record = 1;"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQLCat
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens. Enclose field name in [ ]. It will error if field is not there (field name could not be found) but not if field is empty. Why save this calculated result? Calculate it when needed.

Comment: It does give me an error saying "run-time error '3085' Undefined function 'CONCAT' in expression. Does concat not work for access/sql?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, just saw the & concatenation. No, Access does not have Concat() function. Why would you need it since you are concatenating with & character?

Comment: How can I put all the text in the first row in one field (field 31 Where Record = 1)?

Comment: Just use `&` like you are doing and put an `As FieldName` at the end of it to give it a field name. No need for `CONCAT` - That's not Access. And using numbers for field names is not very good practice.

Comment: Dim strSQLDiscCat As String

strSQLCat = "UPDATE tblFriends SET 31 = ( 1 & ',' & 2 & ',' & 3 & '....' & 30) AS 31 Where Record = 1;"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQLDiscCat

Comment: So do I say Set 31 = (1 & 2 & 3...) AS 31?

Comment: "UPDATE tblCat SET ( 1 & ',' & 2 & ',.....' & 30) AS 31 Where Record = 1;"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because field names are only numbers, enclose in [ ]:

`CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblFriends SET [31] = [1] & ',' & [2] & ',' & [3] & . . ."`

Advise not to save this calculated value to table and instead just calculate in query when needed.
`SELECT tblFriends.*, [1] & "," & [2] & "," & [3] & . . . AS [31] FROM tblFriends;`

Comment: CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblCat SET [31] = [1] & ',' & [2] & ',' & [3]" Gives me an error saying, "Run-time error '424': Object required"

Comment: Do you actually have field 31 in table? Did I use wrong table name? See revised answer.

Comment: No matter what I do it gives me the error saying, "Run-time error '424': Object required"

Comment: Yes, I have field 31 and the table name is correct.

Comment: Dim strSQLCat As String

strSQLCat = "SELECT tblFriends (1 & ',' & 2 & ','...... & 30) AS 31 WHERE Record = 1;"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQLCat

Comment: Yes, it should. You originally showed tblFriends in question but somehow tblCat got into your comment. I had tblCat in answer and changed to tblFriends. Which table name is correct? See if the SELECT query will work. You are not following instructions. Use `[ ]`. Don't use SELECT in VBA. Build a query object.

Comment: Sorry tblFriends is correct...but it's still giving me the same error...I'll try the select query

Comment: The second query gives me another error, "Run-time error '3075': Syntax error in query expression 'tblFriends.* [1] & "," & [2] & "," & [3] & . . . &[30]'

Comment: You are missing a comma after the *: `tblFriends.*,`. As well as a space after &: `& [30]`.

Comment: You got it to work!! :) im just too dumb you wrote tblFriends.* and I wrote that in there instead of tblFriends.[1] &"," tblFriends.[2]...etc after I did that for each field it worked. Thanks!

Comment: That should not be necessary - exactly what I wrote should work. Does for me. But as long as you have it working.